# IE Mode in Edge fails to open in standalone mode

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Repaired this Win 10 Client using SFC and DISM. Slow access to network shares fixed. Following morning the previously working Edge with an Enterprise Site List for IE stops opening in Standalone Mode.

Have tried downloading a fresh copy of Edge from MS and installing then rebooting. No effect.

Have installed all the latest updates including the most recent cumulative update for Win 10 22H2.

Struggling to find any answers from Microsoft and they want paid support for a free browser we cannot uninstall, modify or repair which just adds insult to injury.

Comment: Does it work for another user profile on this computer?

Comment: Also you can do an Edge Repair from Settings, Apps.  That works to repair Edge

Comment: Hi @harrymc  I believe I have found the problem and a repair won't help. It is the Cumulative update for Win 10 22H2 for October 2023. I just installed it on my laptop and it is doing exactly the same as the other client. I had wrongly assumed it was the SFC and DISM repair I did on the previous client. It wasn't it was the Update I installed after I had finished. IE has been finally and totally disabled. A new version of the IE Redirect BHO has been installed and you cannot get round it. The update has broken the Enterprise Site List IE Mode via GPO. Users cannot bypass it, local list blocked

Comment: @John, Hi the repair option didn't help and it needs a fresh download of the Enterprise .msi as it asks for a source disk.

Comment: You probably at this point need to rebuild the operating system from scratch.

Comment: @harrymc work in another profile? it does and it doesn't. The problem is the broken Enterprise Site List for IE Mode. With GPO enabled including Show Reload in IE Button and allow reload in IE set enabled you would think you can bypass but you can't Site List disables both the button and the local list. If I log on as a local account without GPO then I can use reload and manage in local list. Site then opens in IE Mode. The problem is clearly that MS have broken it even in Work Profile mode the GPO Site List doesn't work.

Comment: @John, no point as soon as it gets patched to 2023 Cumulative it will stop working. Have disabled the GPO and deleted the HKCU reg keys to allow user to add back to local site list. PITA though as I need to re add them every 30 days.

Comment: no point as soon as it gets patched to 2023 Cumulative it will stop working.    ......  I have not seen that in a properly working machine.  I will test again.

Comment: Also I do not know precisely what "standalone" mode means. IE will never ever run  by itself again without Edge support. So it may be what you wish is impossible.

Comment: @John, Standalone was a mode in which the site opened in a new Edge window in IE  Mode.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise/retirement-of-ie11-and-ie-mode-standalone-option/m-p/2369960

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge  ....  This mode appears to have gone now. You need to change your source that needs IE.

Comment: the problem is not Edge being corrupted. GPO and Enterprise Mode Site List no longer integrate as they should. Disabling the GPO and deleting the registry keys it creates is a workaround. This puts manual control back and adding the affected sites to the local user site list to open in IE Compatability Mode works again. Standalone mode is a red herring so sorry about that.